# How to Store the Parsed Values in Data base?

Tags: php, mysql, parsing, dom

I Parsed the Matches from this Page:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.espncricinfo.com/rankings/content/current/page/211271.html');
$es = $html->find('table td[class=left]');
```

If I Print the Values:

```
echo "Matches: $es[37]";
```

Its Working fine:

```
Matches: 48
```

I want to store that Value in Data base:

```
UPDATE Table SET Column1=($es[37]) WHERE Column2='123';
```

Its not working. If the data type is `INT` it Storing as '0' and if the data type is `VARCHAR`, then it storing as `table td[class=left]`.

How Can I Store this??

Comment: Kindly DO NOT re post the same question over and over [How to Parse in PHP and Storing in Database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145180/how-to-parse-in-php-and-storing-in-database)

Comment: Did you try using outertext, I tried it myself and it worked a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You should use outertext to get the value of the td.

What you want is:

```
UPDATE Table SET Column1=($es[37]->outertext) WHERE Column2='123';
```

You can see an example of this in http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm under "How to access the HTML element's attributes?" then "tips".

What you're doing is accessing the whole object and what you really want to do is just get the value of the text in the HTML element (that's where outertext comes in).

In some instances you might want to go further in PHP and convert that string to an integer, but I think mysql will do that for you in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to this object "$es", be care it may not be an array, but an object. When echo this object, it will call the magic __toString() method to change the object to string.

And the $es[47] can get the value because it implements arrayaccess or it's type is ArrayObject, thus it could access it properties using array method.

An arrayaccess implement and __toString() example:

```
class A implements arrayaccess {
    public function me(){
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return "This is object A\n";
    }

    public function offsetGet($name) {
        return "value is $name\n";
    }

    public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {

    }
    public function offsetExists($offset) {

    }
    public function offsetUnset($offset) {

    }
}
$a= new A();

echo $a;
echo "The string is $a";
echo $a[0];
var_dump($a);
```

These code will output:

```
This is object A
The string is This is object A
value is 0
object(A)#1 (0) {
}
```

The code is [here](http://codepad.org/xMciC6WH)