# How to Parse in PHP and Storing in Database?

Tags: php, mysql

I Parsed the Matches from this Page:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.espncricinfo.com/rankings/content/current/page/211271.html');
$es = $html->find('table td[class=left]');
```

If I Print the Values:

```
echo "Matches: $es[37]";
```

Its Working fine:

```
Matches: 48
```

I want to store that Value in Data base:

```
UPDATE Table SET Column1=($es[37]) WHERE Column2='123';
```

Its not working. If the data type is `INT` it Storing as '0' and if the data type is `VARCHAR`, then it storing as `table td[class=left]`.

How Can I Store this??

Comment: Somewhere you are not telling the truth. Seems, that the value of $es[37] is really a string 'table td[class=left]' and not 48

Comment: $es[37] not a String, its Integer. When I changed the Datatype as Varchar I found that it reading as "table td[class=left]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `$es->innertext` and not `$es`.
Try this code:

```
$html =file_get_html('http://www.espncricinfo.com/rankings/content/current/page/211271.html');
$es = $html->find('td[class=left]',37);
$query = "UPDATE my_table SET Column1='".$es->innertext."' WHERE Column2=123;";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "UPDATE my_table SET Column1='{$es[37]}' WHERE Column2=123;";
```

Usual caveats about injection and deprecated methods apply