# How to check whether the array is an Integer or Not?

Tags: php, arrays

$scrname is my array. It contains integers and '-'

```
if ('$scrname[2] != '-')
{
 echo "integer";
}
```

it not working

Also I tried this:

```
if (is_numeric ('$scrname[9]'))
{
 echo "integer";
}
```

This too not working.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the single quote:

```
if (is_numeric ($scrname[9]))
{
 echo "integer";
}
```

PHP doesn't interpolate single quotes. So you are asking `is_numeric` to evaluate if the literal string `"$sircname[9]"` is a number.

Comment: In what way? Give an error message. Is there even a 9th element in the array?

Comment: There are over 100 elements. I Parsed a web Page. This is my array. $scrname = $html->find('div[class=cricket-accorContent] table[class=cricket-performanceTable] td'); I think, due this not working.

Comment: Post the results of var_dump( $scrname );

Comment: I looks over 2 Pages. so I post the code here:

Comment: I really can't help you anymore without looking at your data. is_numeric should work. Can you show var_dump( $scrname[9] ) ?

Comment: <?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$htm = file_get_html('http://www.thatscricket.com');

$es = $htm->find('div[class=score_card_results_slide] a');

$value = $es[1]->href;

$link = "http://www.thatscricket.com$value";

$html = file_get_html($link);
$scrname = $html->find('div[class=cricket-accorContent] table[class=cricket-performanceTable] td');
if (is_numeric ($scrname[9]))
{
 echo "integer";
} ?>

Comment: I got Answer from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145180/how-to-parse-in-php-and-storing-in-database

Answer (score 0):

You need to take out the quotes, they're turning your variables into the string $scrname[2]. Single quotes, especially, will not parse the variables as variables.

```
if ($scrname[2] != '-')
{
  echo "integer";
}
```

And

```
if (is_numeric ($scrname[9]))
{
 echo "integer";
}
```